# Why my date is written 0000-00-00

Tags: mysql, datetime

I have a table where the date column name is defined as proddate and defined as DATE.

Here is the code I write the value into table:

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("@Mydate", MySqlDbType.DateTime).Value = Convert.ToDateTime(MyArray[4]).ToString();
```

This gives a result of 0000-00-00

When I change it to

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("@Mydate", MySqlDbType.DateTime).Value = Convert.ToDateTime(MyArray[4]);
```

The result is correct. eg: 2013-11-14

However few lines down I have this code

```
cmd1.Parameters.Add("@date", MySqlDbType.DateTime).Value = Convert.ToDateTime(MyArray[4].ToString());
```

This gives no error. I get the correct result in table

And few lines after I have this code in the same method:

```
cmd3.Parameters.Add("@Mydate", MySqlDbType.DateTime).Value = MyArray[4].ToString();
```

This gives no error too

The last two lines I did the mistake for testing. But the columns of 2 last exemples are defined as DATE format

Any idea ? Or Am I welcome in the mystery world of Mysql ?

PS: I use MYSQL CONNECTOR 6.7.4.0 .NET3.5 and C# 2008 Express. In my server MYSQL is 5.0

Comment: It's usually a symptom of absent inverted commas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the first version, you're converting your value to a `DateTime` and *then* to a string, using the default format for a `DateTime` value. MySQL is then trying to parse that, and presumably failing.

In the second version, you're parsing your value as a `DateTime`, and supplying it to MySQL directly. This is the best approach, although you need to be careful about the input format you're using.

The third version is like the second, just with an explicit `ToString` call. If `MyArray` is of type `string[]`, that's basically a no-op.

The fourth version is providing the string input directly to MySQL, which is presumably able to parse it itself. I would suggest avoiding that form though - parse it in the .NET code, where you have much more control.

Comment: If you get a look cmd1. is exactly the same command where ı get the error with cmd. ??
That's why I am wondering.

Comment: @IsmailGunes: No it's not. Look at where the calls to `ToString()` are. In your first snippet, it's called on the *result* of `Convert.ToDateTime()`. In the third snippet, it's called on `MyArray[4]` *before* the call to `Convert.ToDateTime`.

Comment: Sory! I did not pay where I put the paranthesis. I try then after I come back

Comment: Thanks. I have to change my eyes glasses :) DATE works well with string but not in the form of 1st exemple.